# How do I make a drop down menu?

Tags: html, css, web, drop-down-menu, dreamweaver

```html
<ul id="MenuBar2" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
    <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Item 1</a>
         <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Mr</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Mrs</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Miss</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Ms</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Master</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Prof.</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dr</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is the code that I have used on Dreamweaver Cs6. The drop down works however, when I click on one of the titles, it doesn't select it. Could someone explain how to fix this problem please.

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you please give us the relevant CSS code ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the default Spry menu provided by Dreamweaver, you have to make sure that in the head section that `SpryMenuBar.js` and `SpryMenuBarHorizontal.css` are included.

If so you have also to insert

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var MenuBar2 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar2", {imgDown:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif", imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
</script>
```

before `</body>`

So you end code should look like this

```js
(function() { // BeginSpryComponent

if (typeof Spry == "undefined") window.Spry = {}; if (!Spry.Widget) Spry.Widget = {};

Spry.BrowserSniff = function()
{
 var b = navigator.appName.toString();
 var up = navigator.platform.toString();
 var ua = navigator.userAgent.toString();

 this.mozilla = this.ie = this.opera = this.safari = false;
 var re_opera = /Opera.([0-9\.]*)/i;
 var re_msie = /MSIE.([0-9\.]*)/i;
 var re_gecko = /gecko/i;
 var re_safari = /(applewebkit|safari)\/([\d\.]*)/i;
 var r = false;

 if ( (r = ua.match(re_opera))) {
  this.opera = true;
  this.version = parseFloat(r[1]);
 } else if ( (r = ua.match(re_msie))) {
  this.ie = true;
  this.version = parseFloat(r[1]);
 } else if ( (r = ua.match(re_safari))) {
  this.safari = true;
  this.version = parseFloat(r[2]);
 } else if (ua.match(re_gecko)) {
  var re_gecko_version = /rv:\s*([0-9\.]+)/i;
  r = ua.match(re_gecko_version);
  this.mozilla = true;
  this.version = parseFloat(r[1]);
 }
 this.windows = this.mac = this.linux = false;

 this.Platform = ua.match(/windows/i) ? "windows" :
     (ua.match(/linux/i) ? "linux" :
     (ua.match(/mac/i) ? "mac" :
     ua.match(/unix/i)? "unix" : "unknown"));
 this[this.Platform] = true;
 this.v = this.version;

 if (this.safari && this.mac && this.mozilla) {
  this.mozilla = false;
 }
};

Spry.is = new Spry.BrowserSniff();

// Constructor for Menu Bar
// element should be an ID of an unordered list (<ul> tag)
// preloadImage1 and preloadImage2 are images for the rollover state of a menu
Spry.Widget.MenuBar = function(element, opts)
{
 this.init(element, opts);
};

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.init = function(element, opts)
{
 this.element = this.getElement(element);

 // represents the current (sub)menu we are operating on
 this.currMenu = null;
 this.showDelay = 250;
 this.hideDelay = 600;
 if(typeof document.getElementById == 'undefined' || (navigator.vendor == 'Apple Computer, Inc.' && typeof window.XMLHttpRequest == 'undefined') || (Spry.is.ie && typeof document.uniqueID == 'undefined'))
 {
  // bail on older unsupported browsers
  return;
 }

 // Fix IE6 CSS images flicker
 if (Spry.is.ie && Spry.is.version < 7){
  try {
   document.execCommand("BackgroundImageCache", false, true);
  } catch(err) {}
 }

 this.upKeyCode = Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_UP;
 this.downKeyCode = Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_DOWN;
 this.leftKeyCode = Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_LEFT;
 this.rightKeyCode = Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_RIGHT;
 this.escKeyCode = Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_ESC;

 this.hoverClass = 'MenuBarItemHover';
 this.subHoverClass = 'MenuBarItemSubmenuHover';
 this.subVisibleClass ='MenuBarSubmenuVisible';
 this.hasSubClass = 'MenuBarItemSubmenu';
 this.activeClass = 'MenuBarActive';
 this.isieClass = 'MenuBarItemIE';
 this.verticalClass = 'MenuBarVertical';
 this.horizontalClass = 'MenuBarHorizontal';
 this.enableKeyboardNavigation = true;

 this.hasFocus = false;
 // load hover images now
 if(opts)
 {
  for(var k in opts)
  {
   if (typeof this[k] == 'undefined')
   {
    var rollover = new Image;
    rollover.src = opts[k];
   }
  }
  Spry.Widget.MenuBar.setOptions(this, opts);
 }

 // safari doesn't support tabindex
 if (Spry.is.safari)
  this.enableKeyboardNavigation = false;

 if(this.element)
 {
  this.currMenu = this.element;
  var items = this.element.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for(var i=0; i<items.length; i++)
  {
   if (i > 0 && this.enableKeyboardNavigation)
    items[i].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].tabIndex='-1';

   this.initialize(items[i], element);
   if(Spry.is.ie)
   {
    this.addClassName(items[i], this.isieClass);
    items[i].style.position = "static";
   }
  }
  if (this.enableKeyboardNavigation)
  {
   var self = this;
   this.addEventListener(document, 'keydown', function(e){self.keyDown(e); }, false);
  }

  if(Spry.is.ie)
  {
   if(this.hasClassName(this.element, this.verticalClass))
   {
    this.element.style.position = "relative";
   }
   var linkitems = this.element.getElementsByTagName('a');
   for(var i=0; i<linkitems.length; i++)
   {
    linkitems[i].style.position = "relative";
   }
  }
 }
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_ESC = 27;
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_UP = 38;
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_DOWN = 40;
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_LEFT = 37;
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.KEY_RIGHT = 39;

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.getElement = function(ele)
{
 if (ele && typeof ele == "string")
  return document.getElementById(ele);
 return ele;
};

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.hasClassName = function(ele, className)
{
 if (!ele || !className || !ele.className || ele.className.search(new RegExp("\\b" + className + "\\b")) == -1)
 {
  return false;
 }
 return true;
};

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.addClassName = function(ele, className)
{
 if (!ele || !className || this.hasClassName(ele, className))
  return;
 ele.className += (ele.className ? " " : "") + className;
};

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.removeClassName = function(ele, className)
{
 if (!ele || !className || !this.hasClassName(ele, className))
  return;
 ele.className = ele.className.replace(new RegExp("\\s*\\b" + className + "\\b", "g"), "");
};

// addEventListener for Menu Bar
// attach an event to a tag without creating obtrusive HTML code
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.addEventListener = function(element, eventType, handler, capture)
{
 try
 {
  if (element.addEventListener)
  {
   element.addEventListener(eventType, handler, capture);
  }
  else if (element.attachEvent)
  {
   element.attachEvent('on' + eventType, handler);
  }
 }
 catch (e) {}
};

// createIframeLayer for Menu Bar
// creates an IFRAME underneath a menu so that it will show above form controls and ActiveX
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.createIframeLayer = function(menu)
{
 var layer = document.createElement('iframe');
 layer.tabIndex = '-1';
 layer.src = 'javascript:""';
 layer.frameBorder = '0';
 layer.scrolling = 'no';
 menu.parentNode.appendChild(layer);
 
 layer.style.left = menu.offsetLeft + 'px';
 layer.style.top = menu.offsetTop + 'px';
 layer.style.width = menu.offsetWidth + 'px';
 layer.style.height = menu.offsetHeight + 'px';
};

// removeIframeLayer for Menu Bar
// removes an IFRAME underneath a menu to reveal any form controls and ActiveX
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.removeIframeLayer =  function(menu)
{
 var layers = ((menu == this.element) ? menu : menu.parentNode).getElementsByTagName('iframe');
 while(layers.length > 0)
 {
  layers[0].parentNode.removeChild(layers[0]);
 }
};

// clearMenus for Menu Bar
// root is the top level unordered list (<ul> tag)
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.clearMenus = function(root)
{
 var menus = root.getElementsByTagName('ul');
 for(var i=0; i<menus.length; i++)
  this.hideSubmenu(menus[i]);

 this.removeClassName(this.element, this.activeClass);
};

// bubbledTextEvent for Menu Bar
// identify bubbled up text events in Safari so we can ignore them
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.bubbledTextEvent = function()
{
 return Spry.is.safari && (event.target == event.relatedTarget.parentNode || (event.eventPhase == 3 && event.target.parentNode == event.relatedTarget));
};

// showSubmenu for Menu Bar
// set the proper CSS class on this menu to show it
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.showSubmenu = function(menu)
{
 if(this.currMenu)
 {
  this.clearMenus(this.currMenu);
  this.currMenu = null;
 }
 
 if(menu)
 {
  this.addClassName(menu, this.subVisibleClass);
  if(typeof document.all != 'undefined' && !Spry.is.opera && navigator.vendor != 'KDE')
  {
   if(!this.hasClassName(this.element, this.horizontalClass) || menu.parentNode.parentNode != this.element)
   {
    menu.style.top = menu.parentNode.offsetTop + 'px';
   }
  }
  if(Spry.is.ie && Spry.is.version < 7)
  {
   this.createIframeLayer(menu);
  }
 }
 this.addClassName(this.element, this.activeClass);
};

// hideSubmenu for Menu Bar
// remove the proper CSS class on this menu to hide it
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.hideSubmenu = function(menu)
{
 if(menu)
 {
  this.removeClassName(menu, this.subVisibleClass);
  if(typeof document.all != 'undefined' && !Spry.is.opera && navigator.vendor != 'KDE')
  {
   menu.style.top = '';
   menu.style.left = '';
  }
  if(Spry.is.ie && Spry.is.version < 7)
   this.removeIframeLayer(menu);
 }
};

// initialize for Menu Bar
// create event listeners for the Menu Bar widget so we can properly
// show and hide submenus
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.initialize = function(listitem, element)
{
 var opentime, closetime;
 var link = listitem.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
 var submenus = listitem.getElementsByTagName('ul');
 var menu = (submenus.length > 0 ? submenus[0] : null);

 if(menu)
  this.addClassName(link, this.hasSubClass);

 if(!Spry.is.ie)
 {
  // define a simple function that comes standard in IE to determine
  // if a node is within another node
  listitem.contains = function(testNode)
  {
   // this refers to the list item
   if(testNode == null)
    return false;

   if(testNode == this)
    return true;
   else
    return this.contains(testNode.parentNode);
  };
 }

 // need to save this for scope further down
 var self = this;
 this.addEventListener(listitem, 'mouseover', function(e){self.mouseOver(listitem, e);}, false);
 this.addEventListener(listitem, 'mouseout', function(e){if (self.enableKeyboardNavigation) self.clearSelection(); self.mouseOut(listitem, e);}, false);

 if (this.enableKeyboardNavigation)
 {
  this.addEventListener(link, 'blur', function(e){self.onBlur(listitem);}, false);
  this.addEventListener(link, 'focus', function(e){self.keyFocus(listitem, e);}, false);
 }
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.keyFocus = function (listitem, e)
{
 this.lastOpen = listitem.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
 this.addClassName(this.lastOpen, listitem.getElementsByTagName('ul').length > 0 ? this.subHoverClass : this.hoverClass);
 this.hasFocus = true;
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.onBlur = function (listitem)
{
 this.clearSelection(listitem);
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.clearSelection = function(el){
 //search any intersection with the current open element
 if (!this.lastOpen)
  return;

 if (el)
 {
  el = el.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
  
  // check children
  var item = this.lastOpen;
  while (item != this.element)
  {
   var tmp = el;
   while (tmp != this.element)
   {
    if (tmp == item)
     return;
    try{
     tmp = tmp.parentNode;
    }catch(err){break;}
   }
   item = item.parentNode;
  }
 }
 var item = this.lastOpen;
 while (item != this.element)
 {
  this.hideSubmenu(item.parentNode);
  var link = item.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
  this.removeClassName(link, this.hoverClass);
  this.removeClassName(link, this.subHoverClass);
  item = item.parentNode;
 }
 this.lastOpen = false;
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.keyDown = function (e)
{
 if (!this.hasFocus)
  return;

 if (!this.lastOpen)
 {
  this.hasFocus = false;
  return;
 }

 var e = e|| event;
 var listitem = this.lastOpen.parentNode;
 var link = this.lastOpen;
 var submenus = listitem.getElementsByTagName('ul');
 var menu = (submenus.length > 0 ? submenus[0] : null);
 var hasSubMenu = (menu) ? true : false;

 var opts = [listitem, menu, null, this.getSibling(listitem, 'previousSibling'), this.getSibling(listitem, 'nextSibling')];
 
 if (!opts[3])
  opts[2] = (listitem.parentNode.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'li')?listitem.parentNode.parentNode:null;

 var found = 0;
 switch (e.keyCode){
  case this.upKeyCode:
   found = this.getElementForKey(opts, 'y', 1);
   break;
  case this.downKeyCode:
   found = this.getElementForKey(opts, 'y', -1);
   break;
  case this.leftKeyCode:
   found = this.getElementForKey(opts, 'x', 1);
   break;
  case this.rightKeyCode:
   found = this.getElementForKey(opts, 'x', -1);
   break;
  case this.escKeyCode:
  case 9:
   this.clearSelection();
   this.hasFocus = false;
  default: return;
 }
 switch (found)
 {
  case 0: return;
  case 1:
   //subopts
   this.mouseOver(listitem, e);
   break;
  case 2:
   //parent
   this.mouseOut(opts[2], e);
   break;
  case 3:
  case 4:
   // left - right
   this.removeClassName(link, hasSubMenu ? this.subHoverClass : this.hoverClass);
   break;
 }
 var link = opts[found].getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
 if (opts[found].nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'ul')
  opts[found] = opts[found].getElementsByTagName('li')[0];

 this.addClassName(link, opts[found].getElementsByTagName('ul').length > 0 ? this.subHoverClass : this.hoverClass);
 this.lastOpen = link;
 opts[found].getElementsByTagName('a')[0].focus();
  
        //stop further event handling by the browser
 return Spry.Widget.MenuBar.stopPropagation(e);
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.mouseOver = function (listitem, e)
{
 var link = listitem.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
 var submenus = listitem.getElementsByTagName('ul');
 var menu = (submenus.length > 0 ? submenus[0] : null);
 var hasSubMenu = (menu) ? true : false;
 if (this.enableKeyboardNavigation)
  this.clearSelection(listitem);

 if(this.bubbledTextEvent())
 {
  // ignore bubbled text events
  return;
 }

 if (listitem.closetime)
  clearTimeout(listitem.closetime);

 if(this.currMenu == listitem)
 {
  this.currMenu = null;
 }

 // move the focus too
 if (this.hasFocus)
  link.focus();

 // show menu highlighting
 this.addClassName(link, hasSubMenu ? this.subHoverClass : this.hoverClass);
 this.lastOpen = link;
 if(menu && !this.hasClassName(menu, this.subHoverClass))
 {
  var self = this;
  listitem.opentime = window.setTimeout(function(){self.showSubmenu(menu);}, this.showDelay);
 }
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.mouseOut = function (listitem, e)
{
 var link = listitem.getElementsByTagName('a')[0];
 var submenus = listitem.getElementsByTagName('ul');
 var menu = (submenus.length > 0 ? submenus[0] : null);
 var hasSubMenu = (menu) ? true : false;
 if(this.bubbledTextEvent())
 {
  // ignore bubbled text events
  return;
 }

 var related = (typeof e.relatedTarget != 'undefined' ? e.relatedTarget : e.toElement);
 if(!listitem.contains(related))
 {
  if (listitem.opentime) 
   clearTimeout(listitem.opentime);
  this.currMenu = listitem;

  // remove menu highlighting
  this.removeClassName(link, hasSubMenu ? this.subHoverClass : this.hoverClass);
  if(menu)
  {
   var self = this;
   listitem.closetime = window.setTimeout(function(){self.hideSubmenu(menu);}, this.hideDelay);
  }
  if (this.hasFocus)
   link.blur();
 }
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.getSibling = function(element, sibling)
{
 var child = element[sibling];
 while (child && child.nodeName.toLowerCase() !='li')
  child = child[sibling];

 return child;
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.prototype.getElementForKey = function(els, prop, dir)
{
 var found = 0;
 var rect = Spry.Widget.MenuBar.getPosition;
 var ref = rect(els[found]);

 var hideSubmenu = false;
 //make the subelement visible to compute the position
 if (els[1] && !this.hasClassName(els[1], this.MenuBarSubmenuVisible))
 {
  els[1].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  this.showSubmenu(els[1]);
  hideSubmenu = true;
 }

 var isVert = this.hasClassName(this.element, this.verticalClass);
 var hasParent = els[0].parentNode.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() == 'li' ? true : false;
 
 for (var i = 1; i < els.length; i++){
  //when navigating on the y axis in vertical menus, ignore children and parents
  if(prop=='y' && isVert && (i==1 || i==2))
  {
   continue;
  }
  //when navigationg on the x axis in the FIRST LEVEL of horizontal menus, ignore children and parents
  if(prop=='x' && !isVert && !hasParent && (i==1 || i==2))
  {
   continue;
  }
   
  if (els[i])
  {
   var tmp = rect(els[i]); 
   if ( (dir * tmp[prop]) < (dir * ref[prop]))
   {
    ref = tmp;
    found = i;
   }
  }
 }
 
 // hide back the submenu
 if (els[1] && hideSubmenu){
  this.hideSubmenu(els[1]);
  els[1].style.visibility =  '';
 }

 return found;
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.camelize = function(str)
{
 if (str.indexOf('-') == -1){
  return str; 
 }
 var oStringList = str.split('-');
 var isFirstEntry = true;
 var camelizedString = '';

 for(var i=0; i < oStringList.length; i++)
 {
  if(oStringList[i].length>0)
  {
   if(isFirstEntry)
   {
    camelizedString = oStringList[i];
    isFirstEntry = false;
   }
   else
   {
    var s = oStringList[i];
    camelizedString += s.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
   }
  }
 }

 return camelizedString;
};

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.getStyleProp = function(element, prop)
{
 var value;
 try
 {
  if (element.style)
   value = element.style[Spry.Widget.MenuBar.camelize(prop)];

  if (!value)
   if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle)
   {
    var css = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(element, null);
    value = css ? css.getPropertyValue(prop) : null;
   }
   else if (element.currentStyle) 
   {
     value = element.currentStyle[Spry.Widget.MenuBar.camelize(prop)];
   }
 }
 catch (e) {}

 return value == 'auto' ? null : value;
};
Spry.Widget.MenuBar.getIntProp = function(element, prop)
{
 var a = parseInt(Spry.Widget.MenuBar.getStyleProp(element, prop),10);
 if (isNaN(a))
  return 0;
 return a;
};

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.getPosition = function(el, doc)
{
 doc = doc || document;
 if (typeof(el) == 'string') {
  el = doc.getElementById(el);
 }

 if (!el) {
  return false;
 }

 if (el.parentNode === null || Spry.Widget.MenuBar.getStyleProp(el, 'display') == 'none') {
  //element must be visible to have a box
  return false;
 }

 var ret = {x:0, y:0};
 var parent = null;
 var box;

 if (el.getBoundingClientRect) { // IE
  box = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  var scrollTop = doc.documentElement.scrollTop || doc.body.scrollTop;
  var scrollLeft = doc.documentElement.scrollLeft || doc.body.scrollLeft;
  ret.x = box.left + scrollLeft;
  ret.y = box.top + scrollTop;
 } else if (doc.getBoxObjectFor) { // gecko
  box = doc.getBoxObjectFor(el);
  ret.x = box.x;
  ret.y = box.y;
 } else { // safari/opera
  ret.x = el.offsetLeft;
  ret.y = el.offsetTop;
  parent = el.offsetParent;
  if (parent != el) {
   while (parent) {
    ret.x += parent.offsetLeft;
    ret.y += parent.offsetTop;
    parent = parent.offsetParent;
   }
  }
  // opera & (safari absolute) incorrectly account for body offsetTop
  if (Spry.is.opera || Spry.is.safari && Spry.Widget.MenuBar.getStyleProp(el, 'position') == 'absolute')
   ret.y -= doc.body.offsetTop;
 }
 if (el.parentNode)
   parent = el.parentNode;
 else
  parent = null;
 if (parent.nodeName){
  var cas = parent.nodeName.toUpperCase();
  while (parent && cas != 'BODY' && cas != 'HTML') {
   cas = parent.nodeName.toUpperCase();
   ret.x -= parent.scrollLeft;
   ret.y -= parent.scrollTop;
   if (parent.parentNode)
    parent = parent.parentNode;
   else
    parent = null;
  }
 }
 return ret;
};

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.stopPropagation = function(ev)
{
 if (ev.stopPropagation)
  ev.stopPropagation();
 else
  ev.cancelBubble = true;
 if (ev.preventDefault) 
  ev.preventDefault();
 else 
  ev.returnValue = false;
};

Spry.Widget.MenuBar.setOptions = function(obj, optionsObj, ignoreUndefinedProps)
{
 if (!optionsObj)
  return;
 for (var optionName in optionsObj)
 {
  if (ignoreUndefinedProps && optionsObj[optionName] == undefined)
   continue;
  obj[optionName] = optionsObj[optionName];
 }
};

})(); // EndSpryComponent


var MenuBar2 = new Spry.Widget.MenuBar("MenuBar2", {imgDown:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif", imgRight:"SpryAssets/SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif"});
```

```css
ul.MenuBarHorizontal
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 font-size: 100%;
 cursor: default;
 width: auto;
}

ul.MenuBarActive
{
 z-index: 1000;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal li
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 font-size: 100%;
 position: relative;
 text-align: left;
 cursor: pointer;
 width: 8em;
 float: left;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
 font-size: 100%;
 z-index: 1020;
 cursor: default;
 width: 8.2em;
 position: absolute;
 left: -1000em;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
 left: auto;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul li
{
 width: 8.2em;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul ul
{
 position: absolute;
 margin: -5% 0 0 95%;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible ul.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
 left: auto;
 top: 0;
}


ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul
{
 border: 1px solid #CCC;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal a
{
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 background-color: #EEE;
 padding: 0.5em 0.75em;
 color: #333;
 text-decoration: none;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal a:hover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a:focus
{
 background-color: #33C;
 color: #FFF;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemHover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover, ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarSubmenuVisible
{
 background-color: #33C;
 color: #FFF;
}


ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenu
{
 background-image: url(SpryMenuBarDown.gif);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 95% 50%;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul a.MenuBarItemSubmenu
{
 background-image: url(SpryMenuBarRight.gif);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 95% 50%;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover
{
 background-image: url(SpryMenuBarDownHover.gif);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 95% 50%;
}

ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul a.MenuBarItemSubmenuHover
{
 background-image: url(SpryMenuBarRightHover.gif);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: 95% 50%;
}


ul.MenuBarHorizontal iframe
{
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1010;
 filter:alpha(opacity:0.1);
}

@media screen, projection
{
 ul.MenuBarHorizontal li.MenuBarItemIE
 {
  display: inline;
  f\loat: left;
  background: #FFF;
 }
}
```

```html
<ul id="MenuBar2" class="MenuBarHorizontal">
    <li><a class="MenuBarItemSubmenu" href="#">Item 1</a>
         <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Mr</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Mrs</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Miss</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Ms</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Master</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Prof.</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Dr</a></li>
         </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) to your website and follow these examples:

- [Dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns)
- [Beautiful Dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns)
- [Split button Dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns-split)